# How to skip certain rows while initializing jquery data table?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, datatables

I have a scenario where I've a table which contains multiple rows and below each row I have another row which is basically called as inner row. Now, when I'm trying to initialize data table, I don't want to consider the inner rows. How can I do this?

For eg:

```
<table id="myTable">
<thead>..... Some headers....</thead>
<tbody>
<tr>....some TDs.....</tr>
<tr class="inner_row"></tr>
<tr>....some TDs.....</tr>
<tr class="inner_row"></tr>
<tr>....some TDs.....</tr>
<tr class="inner_row"></tr>
</tbody>
</table>

<script>
new DataTable('#myTable');
</script>
```

But this is throwing an error

> Data tables initialization failed. Invalid Row Count.

Comment: `$("#myTable").find("tr.inner_row").remove();  $("#myTable").DataTable();` ?

Comment: @Brentspine once datatables deletes your `<table>` and creates its own table, you shouldn't manipulate the HTML directly, only going via the datatables api.   Datatables can handle sub-rows, but not by adding directly to the HTML (which may or may not be what you mean by "adding the inner rows", so just clarifying).

Comment: @freedomn-m I don't want to delete the rows with class 'inner_row'. I just wanted those rows should not not be considered while initializing the data table.

Comment: Then you misunderstand what datatables is doing.

Comment: datatables parses/converts your existing table html to data, then creates a *new* `<table>` element based on that data.  The old html is deleted.

Comment: @freedomn-m If i delete the rows with class 'inner_row' it will affect my functionality. Basically the thing is, I have some links in each row, upon clicking on any of the link some data has to be added in the row with class 'inner_row' and the data should get displayed just below the link I have clicked.

Comment: Right, so you need to *include* them when you convert to DataTable.  So your question should be: *how do I include sub-rows when initialising datatables*.   Datatables documentation/forums calls these a mixture of  sub-rows / child-rows and *grouping*.  Here's an example: https://datatables.net/examples/advanced_init/row_grouping.html